# Why Android Studio "Could not find kotlin-compiler-27.0.1.jar"?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, build

I can run the application in debug mode without any issue but once I decide to generate a signed apk Android studio shows me this f...ing build error:

```
Could not find kotlin-compiler-27.0.1.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:27.0.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/27.0.1/kotlin-compiler-27.0.1.jar
```

How can I fix this?

I use `Android Studio v4.0.1`, `kotlin v1.3.72`, `compileSdkVersion 29`, `buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"`, `java 8`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution and it worked but I'm not sure that is the best way

help me if you find something better, please.

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}
```